# MikTex unwork installation

Tags: miktex, miktex-update, miktex2.9

I was installed `MikTex` and use it very well, however, I uninstalled it then download the last version of [`MikTex 2.9.5840`](https://miktex.org/download), after the installation, many errors appear when compiling my `.tex` files.
I tried to update the package (in case there is an important package not installed) and I got these messages:

1. `Error: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.`
2. `Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
   pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "<file name>".tex`
3. I got this error when trying to update MiKTeX using `MiKTeX Update (Admin)`

[image]

Finally, all the packages are installed and still my `.tex` files uncompilable. 
Did anyone have this problem before and how can you solve it?

**Edit**

I try to run update formats but for all formates it didn't update and give errors, here the error for pdflatex:

```
======================================================================

Unfortunately, the package miktex-latex could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/MUHAMMAD/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log
======================================================================

Sorry, but miktex-makefmt did not succeed for the following reason:

The input file could not be found.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:/Users/MUHAMMAD/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:/Users/MUHAMMAD/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

Comment: There are already [questions about "API error 87"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=API+error+87).

Comment: I read a lot about this problem and it seems for the first error that `pdflatex` is running so I close it and this error never appear again, but I can't find a solution for the remaining errors.

Comment: If the formats could not be build while MiKTeX installation you have to build them using MiKTeX Settings.

Comment: Why did you deinstall miktex if everything was working? Close everything miktex related (YAP, texworks, whatever). Open the package manager (admin), synchronize and then install all packages with a miktex in their name.  Open the update manager and check for updates. Then test pdflatex on a command line, not in your editor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I did all that, but I didn't test pdflatex on a command line, I write `pdflatex` in command and it returned  this `"This is pdfTex, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 <MiKTex 2.9.6210 64-bit>`

Comment: Sounds ok. Now try on a command line to compile a small document with pdflatex.

Comment: I tried for a simple document and it still give me the same error, also whenever I Build a file the package installation pop window appear and try to install the missing packages  (While I download all the packages from Package Manager previously)  like `tex\latex\00miktex\pdflatex.ini ` which I found weird, because the `pdflatex` is updated as in above.

Comment: What does the package manager (admin) say about miktex-latex?

Comment: miktex-latex is installed.